# What would a body in an HTTP GET look like?

Tags: http, get

I realize this is not recommended, but I'm wondering what the URL would look like, for example:

http://myserver.com/rest/info?param1=foo&param2=bar

how would you append a body to that URL, I don't think &body would work.

Reason I'm looking at this is I'm looking for a way around a rather limited preset access to CURL from within my chosen language, so I'm wondering if I can use GET somehow instead of POST.

EDIT: Several people marked this as a duplicate of another question, but the essence of my question was "What would the body look like" where the other question is and I quote here [from the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body):

> My questions:
>
> Is this a good idea altogether? Will HTTP clients have issues with
>   using request bodies within a GET request?

Therefore I don't believe this is a duplicate at all, I believe those who marked it as such perhaps didn't really read either question much beyond the title.

Comment: I read that one first, it wasn't the same question.

Comment: The answer _is_ in that question: "don't".

Comment: @CodeCaster: Just because something shouldn't be done, doesn't mean it isn't worth knowing how it *could be done*. Sometimes you just need to Macgyver something.

Comment: Yes, colleagues who come after you and third parties who have to communicate with this service will love your MacGyvering. If it's just a private project though: go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL wouldn't change by adding a body to the HTTP request. In addition to the normal HTTP headers your request would also include a body (separated from the header by a blank line).

I would strongly recommend that you DON'T do this with GET requests though - it is not well treated with HTTP servers and is somewhat wrong if you want to follow and respect the HTTP specification.

A simple request would look something like this:

```
GET /whatever HTTP/1.1
Host: foobar.com
User-Agent: Selfmade telnet
Connection: close

hello world
```

Comment: by "a blank line" would that indicate a cr/lf or a single cr, or a single lf followed by the body, for example if the body was "hello world", what would this look like if you did it manually over telnet to a webserver on port 80?

Comment: According to the HTTP standard (RFC 2616) it is a `CR LF` sequence.

Comment: Added a simple example.